# Steps to install docker daemon on Linux VM

Tags: linux, docker, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

**Goal:**

We are creating dev environments for developers in GCP cloud.

Every developer would have a **dedicated** Linux VM in GCP for day to day development tasks & testing

Linux VM is a dev environment(with multiple tools installed for source code checkout etc...). Docker daemon is another tool, needed, for day to day tasks.

---

So, Linux VM should have docker daemon(installed) to launch docker containers(for testing).

Can we install docker daemon on Linux VM? if yes, please provide steps..

Answer (score 2):

When I build VMs for developers that require Docker, I use a startup script so that Docker is installed when the VM is created. This script can also be used in a terminal window to manually install Docker.

This script is for Debian/Ubuntu systems.

One variable is required. $USER needs to be added to the docker group so that users can run containers without sudo permissions. This script runs commands with `sudo` which is not required as a startup script but is required for a normal user.

```
#!/bin/bash -v

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install apt-transport-https -y
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
sudo apt update
apt-cache policy docker-ce
sudo apt install docker-ce -y
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
echo "User ${USER} added to docker group. Re-login to assume docker group membership."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the document provided by [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04).

I was able to successfully setup docker using the above and once docker is installed, make sure to add your user into docker group. Please refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) link for post installation tasks.

Comment: you were able to setup docker in VM? or host kernel?

Comment: I was to able to install docker as service in VM. If you are looking for rootless installation, you can run the below commands

`curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh`

Comment: Or the best way is to follow the [official](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) documentation.

Comment: we have `sudo` access

Comment: If that's the case, you can use this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/). or you can also install **docker desktop** in linux which I dont prefer